# How can I install Perl's DBI module on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, perl, packages

While I am trying to install perl modules-DBI i am getting this kind of error

```
Permission denied at /usr/local/share/perl/5.8.8/CPAN/HandleConfig.pm line 554
```

Answer (score 12):

```
sudo apt-get install libdbi-perl
```

Answer (score 4):

try to do that from **root** account

Comment: Ubuntu strongly discourages logging in as root and expects you to use sudo instead.

Comment: Now it's sudo apt install libdbi-perl